# How to remove (ban) a twitch stream from recommended?

Tags: twitch.tv

So on [twitch](https://www.twitch.tv) I have 3 channels (streams), which are recommended to me at a given moment, depending on my interest. There is a channel, which I strongly dislike, but the system keeps to recommend it to me. I want both 1. free a slot in recommended channels for another, may be good channel, and 2. never see a name of that channel again.
Is there a way to do it?

I tried /ignore command, it doesn't help.